# Can I get my Gmail chats through PHP/Curl?

Tags: php, curl, gmail, web-scraping

Since Gmail chat is unavailable through IMAP I have been trying to find a way to access them through curl. I know that you can log in to Gmail and read your emails using PHP and curl, but I have been unable to find a way to get just my chats. Is there a way for me to access them this way?

Answer (score 0):

This works for google voice.  Perhaps it'll work for google chat/talk as well.

https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API